# How do I input my train dataset (created via the TF Dataset API) into a RNN/LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset that has around 3621 rows, where each row is a 6x9 2D numpy array. I am really new to Keras/Tensorflow and have scoured the internet to find a way to properly train a RNN or LSTM model (super simple one) with the data I have.

My data was curated into a TensorFlow DataSet so when I print the element_spec of the dataset, this is what comes out:

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(6, 9), dtype=tf.float64, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))
```

So my x values or features have a shape of (6, 9) as a 2D numpy array while my y values are blank.

This is the model I'm trying to create:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(input_shape=(6, 9,), units=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'), 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
)

model.fit(
    train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=test
)
```

And this is the error I get:
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_59 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [6, 9]`

I'd appreciate any help. I'm literally going insane.

Comment: try `train = train.batch(8)`. ps: please don't go insane, it's not worth it!!!

Comment: I tried what you recommended and it didn't work :(